# How to register angular element in vue.js app?

Tags: javascript, angular, vue.js, web-component

I want to use an angular component in a vue.js app, so I tried to create a web component via `ng build --prod --output-hashing none`, to only have one file to include in my vue app I used

```
jscat ./dist/runtime.js ./dist/polyfills.js ./dist/scripts.js ./dist/main.js > ./dist/file.js
```

I placed the file in the `public` folder of my vue.js project and referenced to it by including `<script src="file.js"></script>` in the body of index.html.

I got the following error (Firefox):

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <custom-component> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <Home> at src/views/Home.vue
       <App> at src/App.vue
         <Root>
```

Therefore I added the following lines to my Home.vue view:

```
...
    import CustomComponent from '@/components/file.js'

    export default {
        components: {
            CustomComponent
        },
    }
...
```

(I also placed file.js in `src/components`, to have access to it in Home.vue, may not be best practice...)

Now I get the following errors (Firefox):

```
ERROR DOMException: "Operation is not supported" file.js:4:36473
DOMException: "Operation is not supported" file.js:4:177370
NotSupportedError: Operation is not supported file.js:2
```

Edit #1:

This is my app.module.ts

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, Injector} from '@angular/core';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {CustomComponent} from './custom-component.component';
import {HttpClientModule} from "@angular/common/http";
import {createCustomElement} from '@angular/elements';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        CustomComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule
    ],
    providers: [CustomService],
    schemas: [
        CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
    ],
    entryComponents: [CustomComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
    constructor(private injector: Injector) {}
    ngDoBootstrap() {
        const customComponent = createCustomElement(CustomComponent, {injector: this.injector});
        customElements.define("custom-component", customComponent);
    }
}
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Edit #2:

Chrome Console says:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': this name has already been used with this registry
    at CustomElementRegistry.e.<computed> [as define]

ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': this name has already been used with this registry
    at CustomElementRegistry.e.<computed> [as define]

DOMException: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': this name has already been used with this registry
    at CustomElementRegistry.e.<computed> [as define]
```

Comment: You cannot. Angular does not play nice with other frameworks, unlike react and vue.

Comment: This guy did it: https://blog.fullstacktraining.com/create-and-use-custom-elements-with-angular/

Comment: No, that guy made a web component with angular - you're talking about using an angular component in vue, which is entirely different

Comment: Actually, I want to do the same as him, but I'm not very advanced

Comment: I added my app.module.ts

Comment: @DerekPollard His question mentions to Angular Elements. Angular Elements = Angular + Custom Elements (Which is part of web components)

Comment: @sanju what's your point?

Comment: @DerekPollard thats totally BS. Just use Angular Elements to create a web component that can be used in every framework or website.

Comment: @Mick - if you read my original comments, the whole premise of using an ANGULAR COMPONENT inside a Vue component is incompatible. Angular components aren't web components. They can be transformed into web components, but they aren't web components to begin with.